# Monitoring Web Servers with JMeter

Tags: performance, webserver, tomcat6, monitoring, jmeter

I am trying to monitor the performance of my web server with the help of JMeter. I followed the rules that were given to configure JMeter to test the web server as given [here](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/build-monitor-test-plan.html).

Even after following the steps I am getting a 401 Unauthorized error:
`You are not authorized to view this page. If you have not changed any configuration files, please examine the file conf/tomcat-users.xml in your installation. That file must contain the credentials to let you use this webapp`

I edited the tomcat-users.xml to add the following lines:

```
<role rolename="manager-status"/>
<user username="tomcat" password="s3cret" roles="manager-status"/>
```

Please advice.

Comment: JMeter is using a normal HTTPRequest. Can you access to your web server using a normal browser from the machine were you're executing JMeter?

Comment: Yes, I am able to access `http://localhost:8054/manager/status` from my web browser

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to include an "[HTTP Authorization Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Authorization_Manager)" to your JMeter script. There you specify your credentials to access the site

Comment: thanks for the reply man. I made a new test with the same parameters and it ran fine. Maybe there must have been some errors in the previous test. I hope that there is no problem with running other thread groups alongside monitoring web server because as far as I know that was the only difference between the new test and the old one.